# How do I load data from another package from within my package

Tags: r, package-development

One of the functions in a package that I am developing uses a data set from the `acs::` package (the `fips.state` object). I can load this data into my working environment via

```
data(fips.state, package = "acs"),
```

but I do not know the proper way to load this data for my function. I have tried

```
 @importFrom acs fips.state,
```

but data sets are not exported. I do not want to copy the data and save it to my package because this seems like a poor development practice.

I have looked in http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html, http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/docs.html, and https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages, but they do not include any information on sharing data sets from one package to another.

Basically, how do I make a data set, that is required by functions in another  package available to the functions in my package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you don't have control over the `acs` package**, then `acs::fips.state` seems to be your best bet, as suggested by @paleolimbot.

If you are going to make frequent calls to `fips.state`, then I'd suggest making a local copy via `fips.state <- acs::fips.state`, as there is a small cost in looking up objects from other packages that you might do well to avoid incurring multiple times.

But **if you are able to influence the `acs` package** (even if you are not, I think this is a useful generalization), then [mikefc](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2018/12/10/r-packages-internal-and-external-data/) suggests an alternative solution, which is to set the `fips.state` object up as internal to the package, and then to export it:

```r
usethis::use_data(fips.state, other.data, internal = FALSE)
```

And then in NAMESPACE:

`export(fips.state)`

or if using roxygen2:

```
#' Fips state
#' @name fips.state
#' @export
"fips.state"
```

Then in your own package, you can simply `@importFrom acs fips.state`.

Comment: When I try to export a data set as you suggest, I am given the "Objects listed as exports, but not present in namespace" error. Also, the recommendation [here](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html) is to never export data. Can you comment on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `package::object_name` (e.g., `dplyr::starwars`) anywhere in your package code, without using an import statement.

```r
is_starwars_character <- function(character) {
  character %in% dplyr::starwars$name
}
is_starwars_character("Luke Skywalker")
#> [1] TRUE
is_starwars_character("Indiana Jones")
#> [1] FALSE
```

Comment: I don't get any NOTE...you have your package under 'Imports' in the DESCRIPTION file?